# LLVM: "Invalid bitcast" when converting a struct to identical struct

Tags: llvm

I'm working on fixing some bugs in TinyGo compiler. At the moment, I have a weird problems with bitcasting. The IR code would be as follows:

```
%structcast.go.A = type { i32, i32, i32, i32 }
%structcast.go.B = type { i32, i32, i32, i32 }
...
  %0 = load %structcast.go.B, %structcast.go.B* %b, !dbg !1851
  %changetype = bitcast %structcast.go.B %0 to %structcast.go.A, !dbg !1852
  call void @structcast.go.foo(%structcast.go.A %changetype, i8* undef, i8* undef), !dbg !1853
```

But during IR verification I get:

```
Invalid bitcast
  %changetype = bitcast %structcast.go.B %0 to %structcast.go.A, !dbg !1852
```

I'm wondering, what exactly is illegal about that bitcast?

Comment: IIRC bitcast isn't implemented for structs, only for pointers, ints... and perhaps floats? My memory is fallible and my knowledge sometimes obsolete, though.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, meself figured it out: the cast must be for a non-aggregate type, and struct is aggregate :(